# Navigate to Web urls from Navigation Bar in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Actually, I want to navigate from navigation bar icons to the requested platform like if Github navigationItem is pressed, then app opens the GitHub requested url and if Youtube NavigationItem is pressed, app returns Youtube requested page.

**Note: I am using navigation bar to move through URLs using launcher package url_launcher: ^5.4.11 and not for screen transitioning**

```
 bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.github),
        title: Text('Github'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.youtube),,
        title: Text('Youtube'),
      ),
    ],
    currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
    onTap: _onItemTapped,
  ),
```

And when icon is tapped, it should navigate to the platform according to the input index.

***I mean how should I use the onItemTapped Function to launch respective urls.***

Already I was simply using IconButton's onPressed property for navigation using launch. Just like below:

```
IconButton(
                    icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.github),
                    tooltip: 'Go to  our gitHub profile',
                    onPressed: () => launch('https://github.com/bilalsaeedjh'),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the onItemTapped Function in the following way solved my problem:

```
void _onItemTapped(int index) {
setState(() {
  if(index==0){
    launch('https://github.com/bilalsaeedjh');
    _selectedIndex = index;
  }
  if(index==1){
    launch('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZSgQGG74K2yuEDnbG4U1tQ?view_as=subscriber');
    _selectedIndex = index;
  }

});}
```